# Block MQTT port from windows firewall

Tags: windows, port, mqtt, firewall, windows-firewall

I want to block any MQTT transaction from my laptop. I am using port 8883 as mqtt port as i am using TLS.

I tried to change the firewall outbound rules and added a new rule to block the connection for port 8883. But the port is not blocked as i tried to connect to mqtt server using mqtt explorer application.

Comment: This should be asked on SuperUser